# How to retrieve Image path from Database and set it to imageview

Tags: android

I have images in res/drawable folder.
I have the ID(s) of those images in database for ex., R.drawable.a is a value in the database.

The task is to set the image in that path to the imageview...

I am able to retrieve the value (R.drawable.a) as a string from database, but how do I set it to imageview?

Please post a sample code incase you have...
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer...

It's difficult to work with strings retrieved from database if we store them as "R.drawable.filename". A better approach is just store the filename in database. Then when you retrieve the filename from database as string, you can use the below code to set it to the image...

let's say the file name i have retrieved is "b"
let my package name be "xyz"

```
String test = "b";    
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("xyz:drawable/" + test, null, null);  
imgAlphabet.setImageResource(id);
```

this will set the image "b" in your drawable folder to the imageview..

Hope this helps!!!